# How fast can $\sin(ax)$ be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: approximation

$a$ is a real number. Let $B_n(x)$ be the best uniform approximation degree-$n$ polynomial of $\sin(ax)$ on $[-1,1]$. Denote $R_n = ||B_n(x)-\sin(ax)||_{L^{\infty}}$. Does there exist some function $u(n), v(n)$ such that
$$O(u(n))\le R_n\le O(v(n)),$$
and $u(n)$ and $v(n)$ are about the same (preferably $u(n)=v(n)$)?

Since $\sin(ax)$ is entire function, we know that its best uniform approximation error decays faster than any exponential functions of $n$. More precisely, we can deduce that $R_n<e^{ar/2}r^{-n}$ for any $r>1$, using the truncated Chebyshev series of $\sin(ax)$. Thus we can take the minimum on $r$ and get
$$R_n\le (\frac{ea}{2n})^n.$$
(Taylor expansion can also yield similar upper bound.)
However, I do not know how good is this upper bound, and I cannot get any meaningful lower bound of $R_n$. I guess this upper bound is not too bad and maybe there is a lower bound also in the form $(ka/n)^n$, where $k$ is not related to $n$ and $a$?

Any hint or references on this topic are welcome.

Comment: Reference would be any mathematics textbook with *Approximation Theory* in the title.

Comment: @GEdgar I read some books about approximation theorey and all of them only care about the upper bound. Could you recommand a specific book that mentions lower bound? Thanks a lot.